# lein deploy clojars stuck

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen, clojars

I am on windows and attempting to deploy to clojars. I followed the [leiningen gpg guide](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/GPG.md) and installed [Gpg4win](http://gpg4win.org/) as suggested there; I generated using the default encryption, set passphrase, in short, followed the guide 100%. I have gpg in my path. I am able to follow the guide for generating and publishing my keys. I have copied the public key over to clojars. I have followed the leiningen [deployment guide](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#publishing-libraries) to run `lein deploy clojars`. However, the project just does this and seems to hang forever:

```
C:\project\project>lein deploy clojars
No credentials found for clojars (did you mean `lein deploy clojars`?)
See `lein help deploy` for how to configure credentials.
Username: myemail@mail.com
Password:
Wrote C:\project\project\pom.xml
Created C:\project\project\target\project-0.1.1.jar
```

And that's it.